# Typescript: keyof another parameter?

Tags: typescript

I'm making a function that works with any object like this:

```js
function deleteKey (obj, key) {
  // This is just for an example, but you will get what kind of typing needed.
  delete obj[key];
}
```

How can I give typing in Typscript correctly? Is there a good way to use `keyof` a parameter like this?

```js
function deleteKey (obj: object, key: keyof obj) {
  // This is just for an example, but you will get what kind of typing needed.
  delete obj[key];
}
```

Comment: `delete` is reserved keyword in typescript(javascript), do not use it as function name.

Comment: @Narro Right. I changed the function name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function deleteKey<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): Omit<T, K> {
    delete obj[key];
    return obj;
}

interface Foo {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}

const foo: Foo = { a: 'test', b: 12, c: true };
const foo_minus_a = deleteKey(foo, 'a');
const foo_minus_b = deleteKey(foo, 'b');
const foo_minus_c = deleteKey(foo, 'c');
```